# a difficult task in python (numeric square)

Tags: python, task

> Numeric square
> Unfortunately, the children are tired of snakes, so the teacher needs a new program. Write a program that builds a numeric square of the required size.
>
> Input format
> The first line contains the number
>
> N — the height and width of the numeric square.
>
> Output format
> It is required to output the generated numeric square of the required size.
> To make a square beautiful, each of its columns is the same width.
> [image]

```
N = 25  # Вводим число 25

for i in range(N):
    row = []  # Создаем пустой список для текущей строки
    for j in range(N):
        # Заполняем список значениями, увеличивая значение от краев к центру
        val = min(i, j, N - i - 1, N - j - 1) + 1
        row.append(val)  # Добавляем значение в текущую строку
    formatted_row = ["{:2}".format(
        val) if val > 9 else "{:0}".format(val) for val in row]
    # Выводим строку чисел с учетом форматирования
    print(" ".join(formatted_row))
```

Comment: You should use `{:2}` format for all values, not just when > 9.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Calculate the length of maximum value in matrix and format all numbers in that length.

```
N = int(input("Enter the value of N: ")) # Input the value of N

# Calculate the number of digits needed for formatting
digits = len(str((N + 1) // 2))

# Print the number of digits
print("Number of digits:", digits)

# Create a format string for formatting the output
fmt = "{:" + str(digits) + "}"

# Generate and print the numeric square pattern
for i in range(N):
    row = []  # Create an empty list for the current row
    for j in range(N):
        # Calculate the value for the current position
        val = min(i, j, N - i - 1, N - j - 1) + 1
        row.append(val)  # Add the value to the current row
    # Format and print the row with appropriate spacing
    formatted_row = [fmt.format(val) if val > 9 else fmt.format(val) for val in row]
    print(" ".join(formatted_row))
```

Comment: Note, in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the guidance therein (including that questions should be about narrow, specific technical issues). Best not to let people goad you into ignoring the rules.

Comment: When answering, don't just post code. Explain what the OP did wrong, and how your code fixes it.